# Can I detect UIPickerView scroll events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to catch the scrolling event of the UIPickerView, My app should see if the user scrolling the picker or not to cancel an another event when the user start scrolling.

Comment: [UIPickerViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html)

Comment: yes, but it does not have the scroll delegate!

Comment: in this case, I don't believe it be public. You'll have to class-dump UIKit to find out what kind of view it uses for scrolling.

Comment: ok, this is what i am asking for :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed for pickerview

Answer (score 0):

You can try and find an underlying `UIScrollView` instance by the following routine:

```
-(UIScrollView*)findUnderlyingScrollFor:(UIView*)view{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        return (UIScrollView*)view;
    }
    for(UIView* subview in view.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
            UIScrollView* result = [self findUnderlyingScrollFor:subview];
            if(result){
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil; 
}
```

with the following call:

```
UIScrollView* scroll = [self findUnderlyingScrollFor:_pickerView];
```

and then become it's delegate to get all the calls you need.

```
if(scroll){
    scroll.delegate = self;
}
```